# No Private Setter for Fields - Unit Testing Legacy Code

Tags: java, unit-testing, field, private, legacy

For testing MyClass -

I Have:

```
 MyClass{
         private MyThing usedThing = new MyThing(); 

         public String funcToTest(){
               return usedThing.Fields.something.ToString(); 
         }
 }
```

***QUESTION:*** This is only a section of the method, but my question is without a setter, or without changing the prod code, how can I inject the mocked **MyThing** object into the test?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection for that. It is bad, because it allows you to use private methods or fields outside the owning class, breaking the encapsulation. But testing is a use case where it makes sense.

You can access you private field from your test class the following way :

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
Field field = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("usedThing");
field.setAccessible(true); // to allow the access for a private field
field.set(myClass, myMock);
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically this would only be possible by using reflection, but in such case it is an incredibly bad idea.