# Access private method of an instance in unit test

Tags: java

I came across the following issue when I was trying to unit test my code. If I have a class that creates an instance and for example a getter method like this:

```
public class Test {

   private static Test instance;
   private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

   public  static Test getInstance() {
      return instance;
   }

   private ArrayList<String> getArrayList() {
      return arrayList;
   }
}
```

If now I want to access the arrayList in a test case it would fail, because the list is returned by a non-accessable private method. So trying something like this wouldn't work:

```
public class AccessTest {

   private Test test;

   public void accessList(){
      test = Test.getInstance();
      test.getArrayList();
   }
}
```

So one way to access the arrayList anyway, would probably be to change the visibility to protected. But isn't there a better way to access the method? Is it really necessary to make a method protected only because of a test that needs to access it?

Comment: or package private. In general you would rather test public api. If not, use Reflection API to get access to private field.

Comment: What is the usecase of having the `getArrayList()` method private? It can only be used within the class, and instead of that, you can use the `arrayList` field directly right?

Comment: Unsure whether a true duplicate, but this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24808472/3545273) of mine gives a possible way.

Comment: Unit testing is about testing behavior of a unit in isolation (a unit is not necessarily -one- class!), not about testing it's methods. For that reason, testing something through a private method does not make much sense, behavior is exposed through the (in your case implicit) class interface, so only public methods. A more realistic example would make for a better question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, if you have some private methods in your class and you feel that you have problems with testing them, it is a sign of a bit of a code smell. It shows that too many functionality is hidden behind private wall.

You could change visibility of such method to **package protected**, so JUnit test will see it. There is also a Google Guava annotation `@VisibleForTesting` or something like that. But again - this is a sign of wrong class design.

Think of extracting such method to a separate class and make that methods public then.

For example, take a look at the following code:

```java
class ReportCreator {
  public File createSomeImportantReport(LocalDate date) {
    String fileName = provideFileName(date);
    File result = new File(fileName);
    return result;
  }

  private String provideFileName(LocalDate date) {
    // ... some complex business logic to generate file name based on date... ;)

    return fileName;
  }
}
```

There is a private method `provideFileName()` that does some complicated things and let's say it's hard to test if you would test only `createSomeImportantReport()`.

See what changes if you externalize that functionality.

```java
class ReportCreator {
  private FileNameProvider fileNameProvider;

  public File createSomeImportantReport(LocalDate date) {
    File result = new File(fileNameProvider.provideFileName(date));
    return result;
  }
}

class FileNameProvider {
  public String provideFileName(LocalDate date) {
    return ......;
  }
}
```

You now have option to test that thing separately, focus on what's important in that particular case.

Comment: I agree with this statement in general, but there are situations where you need to test private code and redesigning stuff for the sake of testing doesn't make much sense. `@VisibleForTesting` exists for a reason.

Comment: @uaraven can you give any example where you really need to test a private method? The code in there must be executed from some public/protected method or it has no reason to exist.

Answer (score 2):

Despite the fact that I don't see a use case for a private getter, you can use the package private access level. This is the default access level so you don't have to specify it. You can then test it by adding the test class in the same package name in the test directory. For instance the class is located in `src/main/java/application` and the test class can then be located in `src/test/java/application`.

Comment: 'I don't see a use case for a private getter' - quite right.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java Reflection for that:

```
Test test = new Test();

Method getArrayListMethod = test.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getArrayList", null);

getArrayListMethod.setAccessible(true);

ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>) getArrayListMethod .invoke(test);

System.out.println(list); // Prints the list
```

Create your Test object, use the method getClass() and get the method declared on that class by its name.
Then set that method accessible dynamically. If you know the data type that it returns, then cast it to it.

Comment: -1, this is an awful idea. You shouldn't be crowbarring your way into classes using reflection to test them, it's a sign you're overfitting your tests. This would make refactoring an absolute nightmare. E.g. soft references to the method -> runtime 'method not found exception' but everything compiles fine.